# "java.lang.numberformatexception : for input string :"B50"

Tags: window

I am trying to open ADF configuration XML and the following error occurred while opening the diagram:

> java.lang.numberformateexception :for input string:"B50"

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal exception in Java when you will try to parse the number, but "this" number is not in reality. In your example, your data isn't a number - "or input string" - it is a string.
So, you have to use any methods for work with String